# Ayin Hara - The evil eye - Hocus Pocus

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, ayin-hara-evil-eye, superstition

There are people that do some sort of procedure with lead that they claim gets rid of Ayin Hara. Is this hocus pocus or true?

Comment: Gershon, "Jewish-life" is too broad to make a good tag.

Comment: Better question: Is it permissible? This is uncomfortably close to the German practice of "Bleigissen" described here: http://german.about.com/library/blsilvester.htm
I wonder if there are any solid Jewish sources for it.

Comment: Dave - that is also an important point.

Comment: My Rosh Yeshiva says it works but you should only do it with certain Sadikim. He quoted Rav Mordechai Eliyahu to do every 2 or 3 months.

Comment: However Harav Musafi says: לא כדאי להתעסק בדבר זה כלל .

Comment: @HachamGabriel: How can one know which Sadikim to use?

Comment: @GershonGold he said that he'll give us a number if we want. You can do it over the phone.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I mean this with sincere respect for the rabbi you are quoting, but, to tow Gershon's logic further, how can anyone ascertain that your source (your RH?) is anymore credible than the next sadik he dis/qualifies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you won't find any clear proof one way or the other. I'll just mention that the Tzemach Tzedek ([OC siman 38](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1609&st=&pgnum=104&hilite=)) entertains the possibility that this procedure is effective for certain ailments, to the extent that he allows it to be performed on Shabbos (because of the *possibility* that it might save a life).

For a discussion about which people do this today:
http://www.bhol-forums.co.il/topic.asp?topic_id=1671743&forum_id=771

Answer (score 2):

I know of no source within Kabbalistic texts that state to do this.

Specifically when I asked Rav Kaduri ZTz"L about someone who did it in Jerusalem, he said it was ossur as a Kabbalah Maasit.

Second to that, the "procedure" that they do to remove the Ayin HaRa and prove that it has been removed is an old stage trick, my wife showed me how it was done.

A much simpler and often cheaper way to remove the Ayin Hara that is found both in the Kitvei HaAri as well as in other texts is to carry a piece of a plant called "Ruda". Many Mekubalim carry a piece that has been laminated.  Also there is to hold a packet of salt in one's hand on the first day of Sefirat HaOmer, when saying the Omer, and then carrying that for the rest of the year.

Comment: And the stage trick is... ?

Comment: To make the lead initially fragment and discolor is matter of temperature and additives to the water.  To make it solidify and appear clean, same thing. You can pick up the necessities to do it any stage magicians shop.

Comment: I see you've posted on this topic... http://mekubal.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/being-lead-by-lead/

Comment: Interesting I asked my Rosh Yeshuva, and he said to do every 2 or 3 months as per Harav Mordechai Eliyahu.

Comment: This Michael Tzadok is a RASHA , SINNER AND MAKES OTHER SIN, HE'S NOT JEWISH, HE'S A MISSIONARY, WATCH A MENUVAL UGH!!!  WATCH THIS VIDEO FROM RABBI TUVIA SINGER - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8g71VZrjCpg

Answer (score 2):

If the procedure was done and the evil eye was "done away with" we can't scientifically prove to attribute it to the procedure, however, we do know that such similar procedures were performed and many rabbis allowed it done and did not reject them as mere *hocus pocus*.

The Bet Yosef ([YD 179](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98#.D7.91.D7.99.D7.AA_.D7.99.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.A3), end) discusses a practice to fill the house with incense and quotes Rashba who forbids it because it is as if bringing incense to the evil spirits (cf. Shulhan Aruch YD 179:19). But, Rashba adds that if doing so to expunge of an evil eye it is permitted.

R. Grossman (Ve-darashta Ve-hakarta [vol. 2 YD no. 22](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52054&st=%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%AA&pgnum=177)) discusses the lead practice and, after he concludes that it is permissible to do, he reports that "it is a verified practice" and he personally knew distinguished people who would have the procedure performed for them.

Answer (score 1):

As Mekubal said it was deemed to be Kabbala Maasit which was Asured by Rav Chaim Vital through the Ari 450 years ago. My cousin asked this question to Rav Yaakov Moshe Hilel, and he said it was Kabala Maasit. Once, I found some in my house and asked my Rav what to do, he said to through it out.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my rabbi, a very good Chabad rabbi, about how to ward off an ayin hara and he said, "The best way to ward off an ayin hara is to ignore it."  I am Ashkenazi and I was buying hamsas, wearing red strings, etc., until my rabbi told me I could "go crazy" doing such things and to trust that Hashem is protecting me.  Yet, still, I believe it is a good idea not to tell people of something, i.e., a planned journey, etc., until it is "set in stone."  In general, envious people will try to ruin your life because they are jealous of you.  Even your fellow Jews, sometimes.  The goyim are jealous of Jews and that's where the anti-Semitism starts from.  May we only hear good things.  Kol Tov!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It may or may not be a good idea, but the question was, does it work.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE; I’m not a mekubal, I’m not a rabbi, I’m not anyone special . Everything I have written comes from extensive online and offline research.

Yes I have read many Kabbalistic books, and have gotten advices from many rabbis.

Like Halacha many of it, is just hashkafa.

There’s a book by rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, (Meditation and Kabbalah) there he speaks for a while on Kabbalah Ma’asit, the Ari forbids it though rabbi Chaim j vital used it at his will. And many other great individuals as like the tanaim, amoraim, and many many more rabbis’ afterwards. What they would like for you to stay faaaar away from is kitzufim.

Having your name written then using 99% pure melted led pored on it then seeing the black snakes rush out, is not that. Yes its as good and strong as the person performing it. That’s all

NOW, there are other things that can do wonders as well. Here are the instructions,

Every morning for 40 days  (before netz) go to a Mikve, 
Then during prayers no matter how short you want to make it, make sure you have really strong energy and pure mental space while reading the ketoret and Korbanot. Then read למנסח בנגינת in the shape of the menora (don’t settle for less), after teffila read the Zohar bereshit taman and then the chidas prayer I’ll provide it at the bottom. Following a 10 min taanit dibure. Once all this is completed everyday for 40 days straight you’d be fixed, spiritually clean, free of any accusers in heaven or in any area, that would be harming you in any way. Obviously you have to ask for forgiveness if you have hurt anyone. ( best advice I can give you is don’t stop after 40 days)

CAUTION! If you stop doing this after 40 days and go in the ways of the filth, you will feel the loss, as the klipot and or the walking dead will feed of your light or worse. Don’t be fooled by the modern yeshivas, while learning tora do not speak mundane things, as it will create forces that WILL harm you one way or another; (kav ha Yashar)

Everything that I have written can be found and leaned online on many kosher websites.

The Hida's Prayer Against 'Ayin Hara'

it is good to add the Yehi Rason (יהי רצון)

‎נֶגַע צָרַעַת כִּי תִהְיֶה בְּאָדָם וְהוּבָא אֶל הַכֹּה 
‎נַחְנוּ נַעֲבֹר חֲלוּצִים לִפְנֵי ה' אֶרֶץ כְּנָעַן וְאִתָּנוּ אֲחֻזַּת נַחֲלָתֵנוּ מֵעֵבֶר לַיַּרְדֵּן
‎נָבִיא מִקִּרְבְּךָ מֵאַחֶיךָ כָּמֹנִי יָקִים לְךָ ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ אֵלָיו תִּשְׁמָעוּן
‎נָהָר פְּלָגָיו יְשַׂמְּחוּ עִיר אֱלֹהִים קְדֹשׁ מִשְׁכְּנֵי עֶלְיוֹן
‎נֶגֶד אֲבוֹתָם עָשָׂה פֶלֶא בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם שְׂדֵה צֹעַן
‎נָחִיתָ כַצֹּאן עַמֶּךָ בְּיַד מֹשֶׁה וְאַהֲרֹן
‎נַפְתִּי מִשְׁכָּבִי מֹר אֲהָלִים וְקִנָּמוֹן
‎נֵר ה' נִשְׁמַת אָדָם חֹפֵשׂ כָּל חַדְרֵי בָטֶן
‎נֹפֶת תִּטֹּפְנָה שִׂפְתוֹתַיִךְ כַּלָּה דְּבַשׁ וְחָלָב תַּחַת לְשׁוֹנֵךְ וְרֵיחַ שַׂלְמֹתַיִךְ כְּרֵיחַ לְבָנוֹן
‎נֻדוּ מִתּוֹךְ בָּבֶל וּמֵאֶרֶץ כַּשְׂדִּים  צֵאוּ וִהְיוּ כְּעַתּוּדִים לִפְנֵי צֹאן
‎נֹשְׁקֵי קֶשֶׁת מַיְמִינִים וּמַשְׂמִאלִים בָּאֲבָנִים וּבַחִצִּים בַּקָּשֶׁת מֵאֲחֵי שָׁאוּל מִבִּנְיָמִן

‎ יהי רצון מלפניך ה' א-ל-הינו וא-ל-הי אבותינו שתתמלא רחמים עלינו, ותצילנו לנו ולכל בני ביתנו ולכל ישראל מעין הרע ומכל מיני כישוף, ותבריח היצר הרע והסטן ממנו. וכשם שפרשת כנפיך על אבותינו במדבר והצלתם מעינא בישא דבלעם הרשע, כן תפרוש כנפיך עלינו ברחמיך הרבים, ונהיה מכוסים במכסה והנהגה בשמותיך הקדושים, אמן נצח סלה ועד.

(See Shomer Yisrael, 10)

Tehillim 5 - Chapter 5 - Psalm 5
‎{א} לַמְנַצֵּחַ אֶל הַנְּחִילוֹת מִזְמוֹר לְדָוִד: {ב} אֲמָרַי הַאֲזִינָה יְהוָה בִּינָה הֲגִיגִי: {ג} הַקְשִׁיבָה לְקוֹל שַׁוְעִי מַלְכִּי וֵאלֹהָי כִּי אֵלֶיךָ אֶתְפַּלָּל: {ד} יְהוָה בֹּקֶר תִּשְׁמַע קוֹלִי בֹּקֶר אֶעֱרָךְ לְךָ וַאֲצַפֶּה: {ה} כִּי לֹא אֵל חָפֵץ רֶשַׁע אָתָּה לֹא יְגֻרְךָ רָע: {ו} לֹא יִתְיַצְּבוּ הוֹלְלִים לְנֶגֶד עֵינֶיךָ שָׂנֵאתָ כָּל פֹּעֲלֵי אָוֶן: {ז} תְּאַבֵּד דֹּבְרֵי כָזָב אִישׁ דָּמִים וּמִרְמָה יְתָעֵב יְהוָה: {ח} וַאֲנִי בְּרֹב חַסְדְּךָ אָבוֹא בֵיתֶךָ אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה אֶל הֵיכַל קָדְשְׁךָ בְּיִרְאָתֶךָ: {ט} יְהוָה נְחֵנִי בְצִדְקָתֶךָ לְמַעַן שׁוֹרְרָי (הושר) הַיְשַׁר לְפָנַי דַּרְכֶּךָ: {י} כִּי אֵין בְּפִיהוּ נְכוֹנָה קִרְבָּם הַוּוֹת קֶבֶר פָּתוּחַ גְּרוֹנָם לְשׁוֹנָם יַחֲלִיקוּן: {יא} הַאֲשִׁימֵם אֱלֹהִים יִפְּלוּ מִמֹּעֲצוֹתֵיהֶם בְּרֹב פִּשְׁעֵיהֶם הַדִּיחֵמוֹ כִּי מָרוּ בָךְ: {יב} וְיִשְׂמְחוּ כָל חוֹסֵי בָךְ לְעוֹלָם יְרַנֵּנוּ וְתָסֵךְ עָלֵימוֹ וְיַעְלְצוּ בְךָ אֹהֲבֵי שְׁמֶךָ: {יג} כִּי אַתָּה תְּבָרֵךְ צַדִּיק יְהוָה כַּצִּנָּה רָצוֹן תַּעְטְרֶנּוּ:

Tehillim for success

Psalm / Tehillim 4
‎{א} לַמְנַצֵּחַ בִּנְגִינוֹת מִזְמוֹר לְדָוִד: {ב} בְּקָרְאִי עֲנֵנִי אֱלֹהֵי צִדְקִי בַּצָּר הִרְחַבְתָּ לִּי חָנֵּנִי וּשְׁמַע תְּפִלָּתִי: {ג} בְּנֵי אִישׁ עַד מֶה כְבוֹדִי לִכְלִמָּה תֶּאֱהָבוּן רִיק תְּבַקְשׁוּ כָזָב סֶלָה: {ד} וּדְעוּ כִּי הִפְלָה יְהוָה חָסִיד לוֹ יְהוָה יִשְׁמַע בְּקָרְאִי אֵלָיו: {ה} רִגְזוּ וְאַל תֶּחֱטָאוּ אִמְרוּ בִלְבַבְכֶם עַל מִשְׁכַּבְכֶם וְדֹמּוּ סֶלָה: {ו} זִבְחוּ זִבְחֵי צֶדֶק וּבִטְחוּ אֶל יְהוָה: {ז} רַבִּים אֹמְרִים מִי יַרְאֵנוּ טוֹב נְסָה עָלֵינוּ אוֹר פָּנֶיךָ יְהוָה: {ח} נָתַתָּה שִׂמְחָה בְלִבִּי מֵעֵת דְּגָנָם וְתִירוֹשָׁם רָבּוּ: {ט} בְּשָׁלוֹם יַחְדָּו אֶשְׁכְּבָה וְאִישָׁן כִּי אַתָּה יְהוָה לְבָדָד לָבֶטַח תּוֹשִׁיבֵנִי:

Psalm / Tehillim 57

‎{א} לַמְנַצֵּחַ אַל תַּשְׁחֵת לְדָוִד מִכְתָּם בְּבָרְחוֹ מִפְּנֵי שָׁאוּל בַּמְּעָרָה: {ב} חָנֵּנִי אֱלֹהִים חָנֵּנִי כִּי בְךָ חָסָיָה נַפְשִׁי וּבְצֵל כְּנָפֶיךָ אֶחְסֶה עַד יַעֲבֹר הַוּוֹת: {ג} אֶקְרָא לֵאלֹהִים עֶלְיוֹן לָאֵל גֹּמֵר עָלָי: {ד} יִשְׁלַח מִשָּׁמַיִם וְיוֹשִׁיעֵנִי חֵרֵף שֹׁאֲפִי סֶלָה יִשְׁלַח אֱלֹהִים חַסְדּוֹ וַאֲמִתּוֹ: {ה} נַפְשִׁי בְּתוֹךְ לְבָאִם אֶשְׁכְּבָה לֹהֲטִים בְּנֵי אָדָם שִׁנֵּיהֶם חֲנִית וְחִצִּים וּלְשׁוֹנָם חֶרֶב חַדָּה: {ו} רוּמָה עַל הַשָּׁמַיִם אֱלֹהִים עַל כָּל הָאָרֶץ כְּבוֹדֶךָ: {ז} רֶשֶׁת הֵכִינוּ לִפְעָמַי כָּפַף נַפְשִׁי כָּרוּ לְפָנַי שִׁיחָה נָפְלוּ בְתוֹכָהּ סֶלָה: {ח} נָכוֹן לִבִּי אֱלֹהִים נָכוֹן לִבִּי אָשִׁירָה וַאֲזַמֵּרָה: {ט} עוּרָה כְבוֹדִי עוּרָה הַנֵּבֶל וְכִנּוֹר אָעִירָה שָּׁחַר: {י} אוֹדְךָ בָעַמִּים אֲדֹנָי אֲזַמֶּרְךָ בַּלְאֻמִּים: {יא} כִּי גָדֹל עַד שָׁמַיִם חַסְדֶּךָ וְעַד שְׁחָקִים אֲמִתֶּךָ: {יב} רוּמָה עַל שָׁמַיִם אֱלֹהִים עַל כָּל הָאָרֶץ כְּבוֹדֶךָ:

Psalm / Tehillim 92
‎{א} מִזְמוֹר שִׁיר לְיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת: {ב} טוֹב לְהֹדוֹת לַיהוָה וּלְזַמֵּר לְשִׁמְךָ עֶלְיוֹן: {ג} לְהַגִּיד בַּבֹּקֶר חַסְדֶּךָ וֶאֱמוּנָתְךָ בַּלֵּילוֹת: {ד} עֲלֵי עָשׂוֹר וַעֲלֵי נָבֶל עֲלֵי הִגָּיוֹן בְּכִנּוֹר: {ה} כִּי שִׂמַּחְתַּנִי יְהוָה בְּפָעֳלֶךָ בְּמַעֲשֵׂי יָדֶיךָ אֲרַנֵּן: {ו} מַה גָּדְלוּ מַעֲשֶׂיךָ יְהוָה מְאֹד עָמְקוּ מַחְשְׁבֹתֶיךָ: {ז} אִישׁ בַּעַר לֹא יֵדָע וּכְסִיל לֹא יָבִין אֶת זֹאת: {ח} בִּפְרֹחַ רְשָׁעִים כְּמוֹ עֵשֶׂב וַיָּצִיצוּ כָּל פֹּעֲלֵי אָוֶן לְהִשָּׁמְדָם עֲדֵי עַד: {ט} וְאַתָּה מָרוֹם לְעֹלָם יְהוָה: {י} כִּי הִנֵּה אֹיְבֶיךָ יְהוָה כִּי הִנֵּה אֹיְבֶיךָ יֹאבֵדוּ יִתְפָּרְדוּ כָּל פֹּעֲלֵי אָוֶן: {יא} וַתָּרֶם כִּרְאֵים קַרְנִי בַּלֹּתִי בְּשֶׁמֶן רַעֲנָן: {יב} וַתַּבֵּט עֵינִי בְּשׁוּרָי בַּקָּמִים עָלַי מְרֵעִים תִּשְׁמַעְנָה אָזְנָי: {יג} צַדִּיק כַּתָּמָר יִפְרָח כְּאֶרֶז בַּלְּבָנוֹן יִשְׂגֶּה: {יד} שְׁתוּלִים בְּבֵית יְהוָה בְּחַצְרוֹת אֱלֹהֵינוּ יַפְרִיחוּ: {טו} עוֹד יְנוּבוּן בְּשֵׂיבָה דְּשֵׁנִים וְרַעֲנַנִּים יִהְיוּ: {טז} לְהַגִּיד כִּי יָשָׁר יְהוָה צוּרִי וְלֹא (עלתה) עַוְלָתָה בּוֹ:

Psalm / Tehillim 108
‎{א} שִׁיר מִזְמוֹר לְדָוִד: {ב} נָכוֹן לִבִּי אֱלֹהִים אָשִׁירָה וַאֲזַמְּרָה אַף כְּבוֹדִי: {ג} עוּרָה הַנֵּבֶל וְכִנּוֹר אָעִירָה שָּׁחַר: {ד} אוֹדְךָ בָעַמִּים יְהוָה וַאֲזַמֶּרְךָ בַּלְאֻמִּים: {ה} כִּי גָדוֹל מֵעַל שָׁמַיִם חַסְדֶּךָ וְעַד שְׁחָקִים אֲמִתֶּךָ: {ו} רוּמָה עַל שָׁמַיִם אֱלֹהִים וְעַל כָּל הָאָרֶץ כְּבוֹדֶךָ: {ז} לְמַעַן יֵחָלְצוּן יְדִידֶיךָ הוֹשִׁיעָה יְמִינְךָ וַעֲנֵנִי: {ח} אֱלֹהִים דִּבֶּר בְּקָדְשׁוֹ אֶעְלֹזָה אֲחַלְּקָה שְׁכֶם וְעֵמֶק סֻכּוֹת אֲמַדֵּד: {ט} לִי גִלְעָד לִי מְנַשֶּׁה וְאֶפְרַיִם מָעוֹז רֹאשִׁי יְהוּדָה מְחֹקְקִי: {י} מוֹאָב סִיר רַחְצִי עַל אֱדוֹם אַשְׁלִיךְ נַעֲלִי עֲלֵי פְלֶשֶׁת אֶתְרוֹעָע: {יא} מִי יֹבִלֵנִי עִיר מִבְצָר מִי נָחַנִי עַד אֱדוֹם: {יב} הֲלֹא אֱלֹהִים זְנַחְתָּנוּ וְלֹא תֵצֵא אֱלֹהִים בְּצִבְאֹתֵינוּ: {יג} הָבָה לָּנוּ עֶזְרָת מִצָּר וְשָׁוְא תְּשׁוּעַת אָדָם: {יד} בֵּאלֹהִים נַעֲשֶׂה חָיִל

Psalm / Tehillim 112
‎{א} הַלְלוּיָהּ אַשְׁרֵי אִישׁ יָרֵא אֶת יְהוָה בְּמִצְוֹתָיו חָפֵץ מְאֹד: {ב} גִּבּוֹר בָּאָרֶץ יִהְיֶה זַרְעוֹ דּוֹר יְשָׁרִים יְבֹרָךְ: {ג} הוֹן וָעֹשֶׁר בְּבֵיתוֹ וְצִדְקָתוֹ עֹמֶדֶת לָעַד: {ד} זָרַח בַּחֹשֶׁךְ אוֹר לַיְשָׁרִים חַנּוּן וְרַחוּם וְצַדִּיק: {ה} טוֹב אִישׁ חוֹנֵן וּמַלְוֶה יְכַלְכֵּל דְּבָרָיו בְּמִשְׁפָּט: {ו} כִּי לְעוֹלָם לֹא יִמּוֹט לְזֵכֶר עוֹלָם יִהְיֶה צַדִּיק: {ז} מִשְּׁמוּעָה רָעָה לֹא יִירָא נָכוֹן לִבּוֹ בָּטֻחַ בַּיהוָה: {ח} סָמוּךְ לִבּוֹ לֹא יִירָא עַד אֲשֶׁר יִרְאֶה בְצָרָיו: {ט} פִּזַּר נָתַן לָאֶבְיוֹנִים צִדְקָתוֹ עֹמֶדֶת לָעַד קַרְנוֹ תָּרוּם בְּכָבוֹד: {י} רָשָׁע יִרְאֶה וְכָעָס שִׁנָּיו יַחֲרֹק וְנָמָס תַּאֲוַת רְשָׁעִים תֹּאבֵד:

Psalm / Tehillim 122
‎{א} שִׁיר הַמַּעֲלוֹת לְדָוִד שָׂמַחְתִּי בְּאֹמְרִים לִי בֵּית יְהוָה נֵלֵךְ: {ב} עֹמְדוֹת הָיוּ רַגְלֵינוּ בִּשְׁעָרַיִךְ יְרוּשָׁלִָם: {ג} יְרוּשָׁלִַם הַבְּנוּיָה כְּעִיר שֶׁחֻבְּרָה לָּהּ יַחְדָּו: {ד} שֶׁשָּׁם עָלוּ שְׁבָטִים שִׁבְטֵי יָהּ עֵדוּת לְיִשְׂרָאֵל לְהֹדוֹת לְשֵׁם יְהוָה: {ה} כִּי שָׁמָּה יָשְׁבוּ כִסְאוֹת לְמִשְׁפָּט כִּסְאוֹת לְבֵית דָּוִיד: {ו} שַׁאֲלוּ שְׁלוֹם יְרוּשָׁלִָם יִשְׁלָיוּ אֹהֲבָיִךְ: {ז} יְהִי שָׁלוֹם בְּחֵילֵךְ שַׁלְוָה בְּאַרְמְנוֹתָיִךְ: {ח} לְמַעַן אַחַי וְרֵעָי אֲדַבְּרָה נָּא שָׁלוֹם בָּךְ: {ט} לְמַעַן בֵּית יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ אֲבַקְשָׁה טוֹב לָךְ:

Comment: Welcome to MY! The original question was about if these kinds of things work, not how to perform them; i fail to see how this answers the question as asked.

Comment: Hello!  Yes, though it's only as good as the one performing it. What was written above has nothing to do with hocus pocus, it was the alternative , if you want the actual thing,  "just for the read type of thing" look up the Ayn hara lady (an article on aish.com or ohr somayach) Or i can send you the steps from the gemara itself.  So, Yes they actually do work. Does the tree make a sound when no one is around, the answer is yes, the sound energy is still created even if no one is there to perceive  it.  By not believing, you still allow your blessings to go , take precaution.