# How to remedy a case of possible Ayin Hara?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, segulah, ayin-hara-evil-eye, superstition

If someone gave you a bunch of compliments that you suspected might be based on some jealousy, what can you do to ward off any possible Ayin Hara--at the time the compliments were given or afterwards?

Comment: Who said compliments cause ayin hara?

Comment: Relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ben Ish Chai Shanah Beis parshas Pinchas 13 cites from the gemara in Berachos 20a what pesukim to say to save oneself from ayin harah. He then lists other pesukim as well. See there for the lists of pesukim. Lastly, he cites the custom cites earlier by the Chidah to say Chamsah and make a palm shaped wood piece with the letter of Hashem.

Comment: How does one say "Chamsah", do you simply mean to say that word? May you also please edit your answer to include the actual pesukim?

Comment: @ramin read it inside here http://www.shechem.org/torah/benishhi/sheni/pinchas.html