# Does Ayin Harah have an expiration date or does it last forever?

Tags: ayin-hara-evil-eye

Say you boasted about your great job to a friend. The friend gave you ayin harah. Does this ayin harah expire eventually or does it last forever?

Comment: There are customs that speak of ways to cancel ayin harah, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @sabbahillel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31723 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3460

Comment: It lasts until the person who became jealous does *teshuvah* and instead becomes happy for his friend's success. This is because an *ayin hara`* is an idiom for someone having negative thoughts motivated by *qinah* and *himudh* toward his fellow. The popular mystical conception is a mis-conception. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist what does *himudh* mean?

Comment: @Maimonist, what do you mean when you say "The popular mystical conception is a mis-conception."?

Comment: @Ani Yodea - *himudh* is being negatively desirous, as in *"lo thahmodh"*. And the popular misconception I am referring to is the idea that someone can "give" someone else an "ayin hora" as if it were a hex or a spiritual force that forces God, as it were, to hurt people's self, family, and/or property. Such an idea is heresy. Kol tuv.